# Simulink detect Signal overlapping

Tags: simulink

I would like to get the properties of the signal for detecting if there are overlapping of signals in my model

[image: overlapping]  or if a signal line is not straight [image: straight]

Comment: There, could perhaps be a very convoluted way of doing this by acquiring the positions of the source and sink blocks, and then checking if another source/sink combination is likely to overlap. Could you elaborate as to why you need this info?

Comment: I cosider those two cases as modeling error and I would like to detect it automatically.

Comment: Ok, well, I believe that the second case (line not straight) is sort of buggy Matlab behaviour. I often have components in my own Library that have straight lines, but they show up as diagonals in a Model. Now, for the overlapping part, if you are building the model using the GUI, you can avoid having any overlaps. If you are building it programmatically, then I would say use the `add_block(_source_, _destination_, 'Position', [a1,a2,a3,a4]);` to ensure no overlaps. As far as I know, there is no way to get the path of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Overlapping line in Simulink: Simulink-->File-->Simulink Preferences-->Editor-->Line Hop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).